# Interpreting a log transformed multiple regression model in R

Tags: r, regression, transformation

I am trying to build a model that can predict SalePrice using independent variables that denote various house features.  I used Multiple Regression Model, and also found that some predictor variables needed to be transformed, as well as the response variable.

My final model is as follows;

[Model Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZILh1.png)

How do I interpret this result? Can I conclude that a one unit increase in Years Since Remodel causes a -2.905e-03 change in log of Sale Price? How do I make this interpretation easier to understand? Thank you.

Comment: How to interpret model results isn't a programming question, so it would fit better at Cross Validated (stats.stackexchange) than here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also, if you search for interpreting coefficients in log regressions, you'll find many resources. [This FAQ was my first hit](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqhow-do-i-interpret-a-regression-model-when-some-variables-are-log-transformed/), and it looks good.